# Dúvida consulta SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Preciso de fazer uma consulta MySQL na seguinte situação:

Tenho duas tabelas **anuncios** e **likes**, quando o usuário curte um anúncio é criado um registro na tabela likes com a id do usuário e com a id do anúncio que ele curtiu.

E preciso capturar os anúncios mais curtidos. Alguém tem uma idéia. Estou usando MySQL e PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apenas para complementar e encerrar sua pergunta estou reinserindo sua resposta aqui:

**Solução**

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) as total_de_likes, 
    likes_anuncios.* 
FROM 
    likes_anuncios 
GROUP BY 
    anuncio_id 
ORDER BY 
    total_de_likes DESC
```